# Excel pastespecial only values ignores target format

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have a rather simple vba script that copies trasposed values from a range in a sheet to another, here is the relevant code:

```
wb.ActiveSheet.Range("D2", "D32").Copy
cwb.ActiveSheet.Range("B10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

The source range is unformatted text (no control over this) but it is a time `(xx:xx)` while the destination is appropriately pre-formatted as a time `(xx:xx)`.

It seems that the values in the destination range are treated as plain strings as opposed to being formatted according to the specified rule. As soon as I select a cell and press enter the formatting *is* applied.

How can I trigger the same behavior right when I'm pasting the range in vba? 
The user shouldn't be required to confirm every cell.

I should add that this causes some calculations to fail, too, because to excel those are not numbers.

Comment: Sample data might help and perhaps an image of the before and desired after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the regular **Copy >> PasteSpecial** will not work, you need to convert a time entered as a `String` to time format, which actually a decimal value from 0 to 1. You can achieve it using the `TimeValue` function.

So you'll need to `Set` a `CopyRng` object to the range you want to copy, and loop through it, each cell use the `TimeValue` to convert the string to a Time format.

***Code***

```
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set CopyRng = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("D2", "D32") ' <-- I would try to avoid using Active Sheet

' loop through all cells in your range
For i = 1 To CopyRng.Cells.Count
    cwb.ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Offset(0, i - 1).Value = TimeValue(CopyRng.Cells(i, 1).Value)    
Next i
```

Comment: This is excellent. I'll think over your remark about using ActiveSheet.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer from Shai Rado works, but has the major throwback, that it that it has i reading + i writing operations. I also propose using the `TimeValue`function, but with only one read/write as follows:

```
Function transposeAsTime(SourceRng As Range, TargetRng As Range)

Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
x = SourceRng
ReDim y(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(x, 1))


For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
   y(1, i) = TimeValue(x(i, 1))
Next i

TargetRng.Resize(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(y, 2)) = y

End Function
```

Execute with:

```
Sub test()
transposeAsTime ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2:D32"), 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D10")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the code is really advanced for me. I'd rather use Shai Rado's one as I'll be able to tell what it does at a glance should I need to change something in the future.

Comment: No problem. If you are interested in it i can comment the code for it to be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add the code below (not tested):

```
cwb.ActiveSheet.Range("B10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Wouldn't that copy the source format to the destination range? That's not what I want to accomplish. The destination format should be applied to the new data instead.